# Создание файла и папки внутри директории Debug

Tags: c#, отладка

Мне нужно создать папку и файл внутри директории Debug. Как прописать путь, чтобы не прописывать весь путь (F:\Projects\Programms), а так, чтобы указывать путь из начальной директории екзешника?

Например, я создаю XML файл через код. Он сохраняется в директорию Дебаг, а мне нужно, чтобы в другую директорию, которая уже создана в директорие Дебаг.

Comment: @demiurge, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вам не должно хотеться создавать файл в каталоге, откуда запущен процесс. На нормальной, живой системе ваш процесс будет находиться в защищённом от записи каталоге внутри `%ProgramFiles%`.

Создавайте файлы в `%APPDATA%\<название вашего приложения>`.

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев: На нормальной системе каталог, в котором лежит программа — это подкаталог `Program Files`. Туда доступа для записи нет, проверьте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Application.StartupPath

Например:

```
Application.StartupPath + @"\\Directory\\filename.xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно рекомендациям, в папке с программой не должно быть файлов с настройками, кэша и прочих файлов, которые постоянно меняются. Лучше использовать следующие директории:

- `Environment.GetFolderPath(ApplicationData)` — файлы, привязанные к пользователю, гуляют по домену (например, настройки)
- `Environment.GetFolderPath(LocalApplicationData)` — файлы, привязанные к пользователю и компьютеру, не гуляют по домену (например, кэш)
- `Environment.GetFolderPath(CommonApplicationData)` — файлы, общие для нескольких приложений на компьютере, не гуляют по домену (например, общие для нескольких программ настройки)

Ко всему папкам выше следует добавлять подпуть вида "ВашаКомпания\ВашеПриложение".

Если вы настаиваете на использовании пути к исполняемому файлу, то можете воспользоваться `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`.